# Is there a way to reload all required libraries/files in Ruby for an entire gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've added new methods to Classes in ruby and I would like to reload the entire project instead of changing every instance I've used "require" to "load." Is there a way I can force the entire project reload files so my command line script will use the up to date changes instead of what has been cached from previous loads?

I've tried: 
load "path/to/file.rb"

but I don't want to reload the file every time, I just want it to reload for development purposes.

Comment: I was going to recommend just patching the require method itself to call load, but the problem is gems and stdlib don't work with load. I don't know of a better way than restarting the application or replacing the specific require calls with load

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are doing something wrong.

You should not patch the `require` method, and you should not use `load` instead of `require`.

If you are building your own gem, with a command line interface, then you should be able to freely edit any of the files in the gem's `lib` folder, and it will be used the next time you are running your command line. There is no cached version.

If this is not the behavior you see, then try running your command line with `bundle exec your_command` instead of just `your_command`. As a side note, if your Ruby is installed with RVM, you will not need `bundle exec`.

Comment: I am editing the files in lib but when I try to run the command via command line it says that the method is not found for that class.